# void modifier for constructor causing exception

Tags: java, constructor, modifier

```
public class This_testing {

    int x,y;

    public This_testing(int x,int y){  //Why modifier void here would cause exception?
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        This_testing t =new This_testing(40,50);
        System.out.println(t.x+" "+t.y);
    }
}
```

Why using the modifier void for the constructor This_testing would cause the following exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - 
constructor This_testing in class practice.This_testing cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: int,int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
    at practice.This_testing.main(This_testing.java:13)
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but the line `x=x;` does nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Constructors don't return anything, not even `void`. It's simply how they're defined in the language spec.

You could make a method called `This_testing` that returns `void` but this would be considered a method, not a constructor (and as such, using `new This_testing(x, y)` would not compile).